# Circilar Dependance in python package

Tags: python, circular-dependency

I have a task to make a python package named "project". Inside I have to create 2 separate files with certain names I was given beforehand. Inside each one of them I have to put 1 class with its arguments and methods. All good so far. But here's the problem - each class refers the other one to work properly (in the task description I was given the names of the methods for both classes and some of them had to refer to an object from the other class so of course i used from project.xxxx import Xxxx).

I have the class Library with the method  -

> add_user(user: User)

I have the class User with the method

> get_book(author: str, book_name: str, days_to_return: int, library: Library)

And here I learned about the circular dependence problem. I red some articles how to solve it - to merge the stuff in one file or make more files and restructure the code. That is a no go - package named "project" with exactly 2 files with provided names and 1 class in each one of them is a must since I have to submit a zip file with the package to an online automated system for testing.

The other thing I came across is to put the import statement at the very end of one of the files. I tried on 1 file, on both files and still I get ImportError.

Will be very grateful for any help.

Here is the first class:

```
from project.user import User

class Library:
    def __init__(self):
        self.user_records = []
        self.books_available = {}
        self.rented_books = {}

    def add_user(self, user: User):
        if user.username in [u.username for u in self.user_records]:
            return f'User with id = {user.id} already registered in the library!'
        self.user_records.append(user)

    def remove_user(self, user: User):
        if user.username not in [u.username for u in self.user_records]:
            return 'We could not find such user to remove!'
        for i, o in enumerate(self.user_records):
            if o.username == user.username:
                del self.user_records[i]

    def change_username(self, user_id: int, new_username: str):
        user = [u for u in self.user_records if u.id == user_id][0]
        if not user:
            return f'There is no user with id = {user_id}!'
        if user.username == new_username:
            return f'Please check again the provided username - it should be different than the username used so far!'
        user.username = new_username
        return f'Username successfully changed to: {new_username} for userid: {user_id}'
```

Here is the second class:

```
from project.library import Library

class User:
    def __init__(self, user_id: int, username: str):
        self.books = []
        self.id = user_id
        self.username = username

    def get_book(self, author: str, book_name: str, days_to_return: int, library: Library):
        rented_books = [x for x in library.rented_books.values()]
        if rented_books:
            for x in rented_books:
                if book_name in x:
                    days = x[book_name]
                    return f'he book "{book_name}" is already rented and will be available in' \
                           f' {days} days!'
        if book_name in library.books_available[author]:
            if self.username not in library.rented_books:
                library.rented_books[self.username] = {}
            library.rented_books[self.username].update({book_name: days_to_return})
            library.books_available[author].remove(book_name)
            self.books.append(book_name)
            return f'{book_name} successfully rented for the next {days_to_return} days!'

    def return_book(self, author:str, book_name:str, library: Library):
        if book_name in self.books:
            library.books_available[author].append(book_name)
            library.rented_books[self.username].pop(book_name)
            self.books.remove(book_name)
        else:
            return f"{self.username} doesn't have this book in his/her records!"

    def info(self):
        books = sorted(self.books, key=lambda x: x)
        return ', '.join(books)
```

Comment: sounds like you've at least made some attempt to start coding this. Please post the code you have written so far.

Comment: As given, there is no solution: you have defined an innate circular dependency.  However, the point I challenge is your simple statements of "I have the class ... with ...".  You defined these, correct?  There is where you have to fix the problem: you can't do this.  In fact, I suspect that the assignment was designed particularly to make you learn *not* to do such things.  You have to design classes in a tree structure, not a graph with cycles.

Comment: Since you haven't presented the *real* problem your'e solving, and you've supplied no substantive code, we have no way of helping you around the problem.  Please repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: I've edited the post with full code so far for both classes.

Comment: keep question short with only useful information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's good that you started writing your own code and posted it.

The quick answer is that you don't need to add type hints to your Library class.
instead of :

```
def add_user(self, user: User):
```

you can write:

```
def add_user(self, user):
```

and remove the import statement (`from project.user import User`)

By just changing that, there is nothing in the Library class that needs to know the User class, so no more cyclic dependency, and your code will run.

I checked running this for example:

```
library_of_congress = Library()
tom = User(user_id=1, username="tom")
library_of_congress.add_user(tom)
```

Note: you still need a few other steps to make the other functionality work:
(but that is out of the scope of your "circular dependency question")

```
library_of_congress.books_available = { <put the book info here> }
tom.get_book( <put the correct arguments> )
```

etc

Hope this helps and good luck for the rest of your assignment!
You can read more about type hints in python here:

https://realpython.com/python-type-checking/

https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Comment: That did work. Thank you. Will read the docs. If its not too much please mention anything I should change/improve in the code. If you have any more tips I am all ears(eyes in this case :) )

Comment: Asking for open-ended suggestions on your program is inappropriate for Stack Overflow.  Perhaps Code Review is what you want.